# CSS: show only the last x items in a list

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to show only the last x items in a list using pure CSS?

The following code snippet shows every item, except for the first 2. How do I only show the last two items in a list?

```
ul li {
    display: none !important;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(2) ~ li {
    display: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/mechskt2/

use `:nth-last-of-type(-n+x)` or `:nth-of-type(n+x)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [nth-last-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-of-type/).

```
ul li:nth-last-of-type(2),
ul li:nth-last-of-type(2) ~ li {
    display: inherit !important;
}
```